# How to catch two CLI options and their arguments with getopt?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm trying to make a python script able to take two options at once, like in this example :

```
$ python main.py -o param1 -t table1
```

And I want to be able to have two different behaviours; if there is no `-t` argument, I want my script to treat all my csv tables, and if there is a -t argument, I want it to treat only the table given in the argument.

I use something like this :

```
import getopt, sys

def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hs:v:t:", ["help", "start=", "table="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        # print help information and exit:
        print str(err) # will print something like "option -a not recognized"
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    for o, a in opts:
        if o == "-v":
            verbose = True
        elif o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif o in ("-s", "--start"):
            start = a
        else:
            assert False, "unhandled option"
    # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I do: `print opts`

I will find: `[('-o', 'param1'), ('-t', 'table1')]`

But I'm unable to find a way to get the second option argument.
Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: if you are able, i would suggest switching to argparse. it is built in to 2.7 and 3+ and there is an argparse backport for earlier versions in pypi.

Comment: Why don't you have an `elif o in ("-t")` clause?

Comment: i want the possibility to see if a first option is verified and then if there is a second option i do something specific. For example: elif o in ("-h", "--help"): if a in ("-t", "--table"): table = arg

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm unable to find a way to get the second option argument". Which argument are you talking about specifically?

Comment: the second argument is table1

Answer (score 0):

You really would be better using something which gives you a dict of arguments, perhaps like [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt), but if you must use getopt, here you go:

```
>>> opts = [('-o', 'param1'), ('-t', 'table1')]
>>> for a,b in opts:
...     if a == '-t':
...         table = b
>>> print table
table1
```